# How to pass a column name value as SQL argument using placeholders

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, placeholder

How to pass a column name value as a SQL argument using parameter placeholders ?

The goal is having this working:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE @0 LIKE @1";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,choice,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

`choice` is a variable that will store the `column name`

`@0` is a `column name` (and I don't succeed to pass it as an argument)

`@1` is a `search string` (and I have no problem with it)

Have read and tried a lot of things:

Below one doesn't throw any error but doesn't bring any data

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE @0 LIKE @1";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,choice,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

Below one throws `Column name not valid = '@0'`

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE [@0] LIKE @1"
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,choice,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

Below one throws `Column name not valid = 'choice'`

```
var sql "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE choice LIKE @0");
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

Below one throws `Must declare scalar variable "@choice"`

```
var sql "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE @choice LIKE @0");
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

Below one doesn't throw any error but doesn't bring any data

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE '@choice' LIKE @0";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

Below one doesn't throw any error but doesn't bring any data

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE '@choice' LIKE @0";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

Below one doesn't throw any error but doesn't bring any data

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE '"+choice+"' LIKE @0";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

Below one: BIG CRASH

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE '"+@choice+"' LIKE @0";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

Below one throws `Column name not valid = 'NameShort'`

**This is precisely the correct column name**

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE ['"+choice+"'] LIKE @0";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

Below one: BIG CRASH

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE ['"+@choice+"'] LIKE @0";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

**HELP !!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: what rdbms are you using?  sql server, mysql, oracle?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Express in WebMatrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't; parameters are only supported for **values**, not for **column names**.

You either have to fall back on direct text insertion as Richard has said (whether this happens in code or via the use of the SQL Server exec() function), or use some kind of a library (like LINQ) that lets you construct queries dynamically and then converts that into a text representation.

If you go the direct text insertion route, **be very sure that you are not allowing direct user input to be inserted; do some kind of translation yourself** to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "do some kind of translation yourself" ?

Comment: I mean that you need to do something like checking that the column name matches a valid column name exactly, rather than just doing a blind "where " + column + " = 'foo'". A switch statement, an if block, construct an Expression, something to make sure that the column is a valid column name for the table and not a potentially dangerous value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at what you've tried, and you've just left out the obvious one:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE " + choice + " LIKE @1";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,choice,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

The only reason you will need to escape the column name is when it is a reserved word, such as `Order`.  In that case, you will need to use the database-specific identifier escape character.

For example, MySQL:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE `" + choice + "` LIKE @1";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,choice,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

SQL Server

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Condos WHERE [" + choice + "] LIKE @1";
var sqlData = db.Query(sql,choice,"%"+searchString+"%");
```

Comment: Thanks Richard for your comments but it didn't work out !! No error but no data !! I could well create a different SQL statement for each choice (and that's what I used up to now) but I don't find it to be very "elegant" !

Comment: Richard. I'm not an idiot and would ask you to remain polite. I'm probably not (yet) an expert as you are but am doing quite well as a novice ! I tried what you suggested and it didn't work out. I must admit I made an error when trying your solution: I used placeholder @0 instead of @1. There was an additional issue in case the user didn't select anything but it is solved. What about SQL injection here ?