# Dynamic table name in Excel SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, dynamic, parameters, tablename

I couldn't find any solution to set a SQL query in Excel with a dynamic table name which is in one of the cells in the workbook.

```
LEFT JOIN [param!$a$5] B ON B.LOGICALREF = H.ACCFICHEREF
```

`param!a5` has the name of the table.

More info : i have several tables and the names of the tables differ construction site to site ( 91, 90 , 89 as "LG_086_EMUHACC" ) I want to execute the query for each site as i change the code of the site.

Comment: Y need to supply more info

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=170045

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a column name value as SQL argument using placeholders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537629/how-to-pass-a-column-name-value-as-sql-argument-using-placeholders)

Comment: More info : i have several tables and the names of the tables differ construction site to site ( 91, 90 , 89 as   "LG_086_EMUHACC" ) I want to execute the query for each site as i change the code of the site.